# Could "VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed" solution break Win update?

Tags: updating

I run "VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed" solution  http://goo.gl/S1jXp.

Could this cause Windows 7 64 bit to fail installing updates?  (Error code 641 in Windows Update  http://goo.gl/5ttfP)
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"

Comment: How to undo his command?

 regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"

Comment: try this. regsvr32.exe /U "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll